# AndroidのDrawableリソースにアクセス出来ない

Tags: android, android-layout

こちらのサイト([http://androiddrawables.com/Other.html)](http://androiddrawables.com/Other.html)で見られる`ic_btn_round_more_disabled`というAndroid標準の`Drawable`リソースを使いたいと思い次のコードで参照しようとしたのですが､シンボルを解決できないというエラーが出てしまいました｡

**コード:**

```
indicateButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_round_more_disabled);
```

`indicatorButton`というのは`Button`ではなく`ImageView`です｡紛らわしくてすみません｡
そこで､他にこのリソースを使う方法はありますでしょうか｡
`Android-SDK`は`API21`です｡

Answer (score 3, accepted):

android.R.drawable に定数がないということは、framework の private な
リソースです。
無理やりアクセスする方法はないことはないですが、private なものに関しては
端末によっては存在しなかったり全く異なる画像になっている可能性があります。

このようなものを使いたい場合は、 AOSP のサイトからソースコードをダウンロードし
使いたいdrawable のファイルをアプリにコピーしてください。
AOSP で配布されているものは大部分 Apache License 2.0 で、ほとんどの画像も
このライセンスに従い使用することが出来ます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。AOSPから拝借しました。

Answer (score 1):

多分ですが、`android`パッケージにある`R`クラスでは？

```
indicateButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_round_more_disabled);
```

Comment: @fkm様
`android/R.class`を見たのですが､`ic_btn`で始まるものは`ic_btn_speak_now`という名前のものしかありませんでした｡
`android.jar/res/drawable`には`ic_btn_round_more.xml`とうXMLファイルがあって､中身は文字化けしていて読めませんでした｡
また､`android.jar`と同列のフォルダにも`res`というファイルがあってその中にも`res/drawable/ic_btn_round_more.xml`というファイルがあってその中身は
    `<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   
 <item android:state_enabled="false"
       
 android:drawable="@drawable/ic_btn_round_more_disabled" />
    
<item
         android:drawable="@drawable/ic_btn_round_more_normal" />`

</selector>`

と書かれていました｡

Answer (score 1):

```
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("ic_btn_round_more_disabled", "drawable", "android");
    indicateButton.setImageResource(resourceId);
```